# How do I align the text inside list elements when styling with TailwindCSS Typography?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm re-styling my personal blog using TailwindCSS Typography plugin. The index page lists all the posts I've written in the format `yyyy-mm-dd - title`. My problem is that `- title` is not aligned in the same column and moves left or right depending on the date.

Here is a minimal HTML example to reproduce the problem:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing Tailwind CSS text alignment</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=typography"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="post-body" class="mx-auto prose prose-stone prose-ul:list-none px-2 lg:px-0">
      <h1>Programming</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><span>2020-08-22</span><span> - </span><a href="230A6048.html">Blog Post Title 1</a></li>
        <li><span>2018-12-15</span><span> - </span><a href="F6A029B0.html">Blog Post Title 2</a></li>
        <li><span>2012-02-23</span><span> - </span><a href="76191EE8.html">Blog Post Title 3</a></li>
        <li><span>2011-08-07</span><span> - </span><a href="1DE16EA3.html">Blog Post Title 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here, you will see that the `-` in the second item (date: 2018-12-15) is misaligned. How does one fix this? I've tried a bunch of different techniques which all failed, so I'm asking here in the hopes someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

This has not much to do with tailwind or the plugin. It is caused by the fact that [most used fonts are proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion). So the 'i' takes less space than the 'w'. There are several options to align the text.

You could use an `monospaced` font (like in the code block), but usually these not quite nice. To show this, I have used the `pre` tag in the code snippet, in tailwind you can use the class `font-mono`.

A better solution is to use [a table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp), so you will have real aligned columns. So that even when the number of characters is different, the text is still aligned. Be aware that the tailwind typography will also style the table, which usually is a good thing, but maybe not in this situation.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing Tailwind CSS text alignment</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="post-body" class="mx-auto prose prose-stone prose-ul:list-none px-2 lg:px-0">
      <h1>Table</h1>
      <table>
        <tr><td>2011-01-11</td><td> - </td><td><a href="230A6048.html">Blog Post Title 1</a></td></tr>
        <tr><td>20-8-12</td><td> - </td><td><a href="230A6048.html">Blog Post Title 2</a></td></tr>
        <tr><td>2014-3-18</td><td> - </td><td><a href="230A6048.html">Blog Post Title 3</a></td></tr>
        <tr><td>2020-08-22</td><td> - </td><td><a href="230A6048.html">Blog Post Title 4</a></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <pre>
    <div><h1>Monospaced</h1><ul>
         <li><span>2011-01-07</span><span> - </span><a href="1DE16EA3.html">Blog Post Title 4</a></li>
          <li><span>2018-08-07</span><span> - </span><a href="1DE16EA3.html">Blog Post Title 4</a></li>
           <li><span>2013-04-07</span><span> - </span><a href="1DE16EA3.html">Blog Post Title 4</a></li>
            <li><span>2022-06-07</span><span> - </span><a href="1DE16EA3.html">Blog Post Title 4</a></li>
      </ul></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could also use display: table.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Could you provide a code snippet for that? I would like to know how that works.

Comment: * `display:table` didn't help much (In tailwind this is done by adding the `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell` classes, which didn't change anything)

* Converting the `ul/li` to `table/tr/td` didn't help either. It _did_ align the text properly, but the problem is that I have multiple such sections ("Programming" followed by "Random" "Literature" etc) and in each section the table aligns differently, depending on whether there is more that one element in the table.

* `pre` just makes the whole thing look terrible :(

Comment: Yeah, `pre` is awful. But can’t you just set a fixed width on the `td` with the date (first column), like `w-20` which is the same in every section? I think you need to set `table-auto` on the table. If it doesn’t work on the `td`, you could place a `div` in the `td` and set a width on that. You also could take a look at `grid`. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns